# How to get $resultRedirect->setPath() data in afterExecute plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have written a plugin for few changes and all working well.

Now I want to get redirect data E.g setPath and main id in **afterExecute** plugin

**Here is my code**

```
    <?php

namespace Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends \Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && !empty($data)) {
            try {
                $id = $this->saveDemo($data);
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $id]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                $this->_getSession()->setSharingForm($this->getRequest()->getParams());
            }
        }

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    private function saveDemo(array $data)
    {
    
    }
}
```

**Plugin code**

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Base\Plugin\Frontend\Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;
class Save
{
   
    public function afterExecute(\Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo\Save $subject, $result)
    {
        var_dump($result->getPath());
        return $result;
    }
}
```

please guide me on how can I get id from setPath. is it the correct way? or any other way
Any help Appreciate

Thanks

Comment: have you tried print_r($this->getRequest()->getParams());  ?

Comment: yes tried but it not working it just giving post data...

Comment: $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl() try this to get previous url

Comment: try using di 

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 


$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

        // Your code

     print_r( $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

Comment: already try it not working it gives the only last URL .. i want id from setPath

Comment: easy way save in coresession of magento and get where you want after fetch unset it

Comment: actually its third party module and i don't want override controller so i want to get somehow via plugins

Comment: its not bad approach you can override it as first priority is plugin then  override the file